# Number of Labels Always 1/3rd the Number of Features

Tags: python, opencv

Going through a [Sentdex Deep Learning tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-3vuBynnOE), I'm trying to figure out why the number of labels in my training set is always 1/3rd of the number of features.  Not sure why this is happening.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import random
import cv2
import pickle

IMG_SIZE = 50
DATADIR = r"D:\Machine Learning\all\train\train"
CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]

training_data = []
def createTrainingData():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                print(img)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass

createTrainingData()
random.shuffle(training_data)
X = []
y = []

for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

print(len(X))
print(len(y))

pickle_out = open("X.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()


pickle_out = open("y.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

Comment: How many images of Cats and Dogs do you have in the subfolders and what is the output of
print(len(X)) and print(len(y))?

Comment: @Suleiman Both have 12499, and print(len(X)) is 75000, while print(len(y)) is 25000.

Comment: Immediately after create `TrainingData()` try to run `print(len(training_data))` and what is the output?

Comment: @Suleiman so for whatever reason, I changed the last argument of .reshape to 1/3rd, which tossed an error. I then changed it back to 1, and then for whatever reason the program correctly stated that there were 25000 features and 25000 labels.  So problem solved, but oddly.

Comment: That's weird but glad you got it fixed. Post the way you solved it as answer your own question for others in future that may experience same.

Answer (score 0):

So for whatever reason, I changed the last argument of .reshape to 1/3rd, which tossed an error. I then changed it back to 1, and then for whatever reason the program correctly stated that there were 25000 features and 25000 labels. So problem solved, but oddly.